# Difference in usage and nuance between "couper l’envie" and "passer l’envie"?

Tags: usage

> Avec un tel parfum pas très appétissant, ça risquerait de **couper l’envie** aux gens d’en manger.

I tend to use "couper l’envie" when something puts you off doing something casual like eating ice cream, whereas "passer l’envie" is reserved for a situation that makes you think twice about venturing to do something that may well have some serious repercussions. Given this, "passer l’envie" is often used in a mildly threatening way, the way I see it.

I can't imagine myself saying "passer l’envie" in this specific instance. Or am I reading too much into things here?

> Avec un tel parfum pas très appétissant, ça risquerait de **passer l’envie** aux gens d’en manger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second form should be *[faire passer l'envie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_passer_l%E2%80%99envie_de_quelque_chose)*.

The nuance I see is for *couper l'envie* to be something that happens relatively quickly while *faire passer l'envie* is more gradual.  You are right the second expression is also sometimes related to threatening situations, e.g. :

> Je vais te faire passer l'envie de garer ta voiture devant mon garage !

Comment: Hi. About "faire", what do you think of: "Voilà qui devrait lui ***passer*** l'envie de se moquer de Sophia à l'avenir !"? Somehow, I feel more comfortable leaving "faire" out in this instance.

Comment: Yes, dropping *faire* happens but IMHO only in colloquial French. This doesn't match the formal tone of the remaining part of your sentence..

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you think you can also drop "faire" in the construction "ça risquerait de (***faire***) ***passer*** l’envie aux gens d’en manger"?

Comment: Dropping *faire* here sounds odd/incorrect to me.

Comment: Hi. Regarding "faire passer l'envie", how would you translate your "garage" example sentence into English?

Comment: Maybe: "I'll make you wish that you never parked your car in front of my garage!"

Comment: So do you say this "garage" sentence after someone has actually parked their car in front of your garage? I wonder if "faire passer l'envie" (when used in a threatening manner) is close in meaning to "Ça t’apprendra à garer ta voiture devant mon garage !"?

Comment: Now that I think on it, perhaps "couper l’envie" denotes "putting someone off doing something ***before*** they actually do it", whereas "passer l’envie" denotes "putting someone off doing something ***after*** they have actually done it or when they are already ***in the middle of*** doing it"?